# What is the difference between PropertyEditor, Formatter and Converter in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Working with `Spring MVC` it turns out that I can bind my forms in many different ways and I really feel like I'm getting lost. The `parse` and `print` methods of a `Formatter` are equivalent to those of a `PropertyEditorSupport` with a different name (`getAsText` and `setAsText`). Similarly, I can implement either a `GenericConverter`  or two `Converter<S,T>`s to do exactly the same thing.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544479/spring-mvc-type-conversion-propertyeditor-or-converter) in a comment that `Formatters` are a replacement for `PropertyEditor`, but I haven't found any documentation to support it and it hasn't even been Deprecated neither.

My question is, when it comes to bind data from a form to an object, what is the correct way to do it in `spring-mvc`? What is the main difference between `PropertyEditor`, `Formatter` and `Converter` in Spring? What are the use cases for each one? For me it looks like they have the same responsibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To help to understand these concepts I would differentiate first the Spring specific functionality from that exposed from Java.

`PropertyEditor`s and [the related stuff](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/package-summary.html) are defined by the [JavaBeans Specification](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javabeans-spec.html).

The specification defines an API, mechanisms and conventions for dealing with objects, objects properties, and everything related to their changes, as events.

`PropertyEditor`s are typically used in GUIs to handle the interaction between an UI and the underlying objects model, typically handling the conversion between properties values from/to its `String` representation.

Spring itself actually uses different `PropertyEditor` implementations and Java Beans conventions in many different situations. For example, from the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-beans-conversion):

> A couple of examples where property editing is used in Spring:
>
> - Setting properties on beans is done by using `PropertyEditor`
>   implementations. When you use String as the value of a property of some
>   bean that you declare in an XML file, Spring (if the setter of the
>   corresponding property has a `Class` parameter) uses `ClassEditor` to try
>   to resolve the parameter to a `Class` object.
> - Parsing HTTP request parameters in Spring’s MVC framework is done by
>   using all kinds of `PropertyEditor` implementations that you can manually
>   bind in all subclasses of the `CommandController`.

In summary, `PropertyEditor`s allow you for a broader number of use cases.

Now, in the Spring world you need to do a differentiation as well between Spring MVC and Spring Core.

Please, note that both the [Convert](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#core-convert) and the [Formatter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#format) stuff are defined as core technologies, of relevance to any use case and not limited to the web framework.

The Spring documentation, when describing [Spring Field Formatting](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#format), provides a great explanation about the purpose of every API/SPI and how they are related to `PropertyEditor`s as well:

> As discussed in the previous section, `core.convert` is a general-purpose
> type conversion system. It provides a unified `ConversionService` API as
> well as a strongly typed Converter SPI for implementing conversion logic
> from one type to another. A Spring container uses this system to bind bean
> property values. In addition, both the Spring Expression Language (SpEL)
> and `DataBinder` use this system to bind field values. For example, when
> SpEL needs to coerce a `Short` to a `Long` to complete an
> `expression.setValue(Object bean, Object value)` attempt, the `core.convert`
> system performs the coercion.
>
> Now consider the type conversion requirements of a typical client
> environment, such as a web or desktop application. In such environments,
> you typically convert from `String` to support the client postback process,
> as well as back to `String` to support the view rendering process. In
> addition, you often need to localize `String` values. The more general
> core.convert Converter SPI does not address such formatting requirements
> directly. To directly address them, Spring 3 introduced a convenient
> Formatter SPI that provides a simple and robust alternative to
> `PropertyEditor` implementations for client environments.
>
> In general, you can use the Converter SPI when you need to implement
> general-purpose type conversion logic — for example, for converting between
> a `java.util.Date` and a `Long`. You can use the Formatter SPI when you
> work in a client environment (such as a web application) and need to parse
> and print localized field values. The `ConversionService` provides a
> unified type conversion API for both SPIs.

In the specific use case of Spring MVC the framework itself is able to handle  simple types when [handling the HTTP requests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-methods).

[Type conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-typeconversion) is automatically applied based on the configured set of converters, although that behavior can be tweaked using [`DataBinder`s](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-initbinder) and the aforementioned Formatting system. Please, see the [relevant docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-config-conversion).

In a typical use case in which you deal with reading and writing the body of HTTP requests and responses, when using the [`@RequestBody`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-requestbody), for example, Spring will use a bunch of different pre-[configured](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-config-message-converters) [`HttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#rest-message-conversion) implementations: the actual ones registered will depend on your configuration and the libraries imported in your project - say Jackson, for example. I was unable to find that point in the documentation but here is the link to the actual [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/d84ca2ba90d27a7c63d7b35a6259b5b9cf341118/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java#L896-L965).

Please, consider review [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64370226/add-custom-decoder-to-webmvc-endpoint/64412472#64412472), it could be of help.

Comment: Thanks for that amazing answer. Everything became much clearer to me knowing which package each interface belonged to, now everything makes sense. On the other hand, I'm glad the same documentation exposed `Formatter SPI` as an alternative to `PropertyEditor`, that was just what I needed to read, plus the detail that it was included in version 3. In practice I always implemented `Formatters` because for me they made the code much easier to read, reuse and maintain, but I didn't know if that approach was correct. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You are very welcome @Jaime. Thank you very much for your comment. I am very happy to hear that the answer was helpful. Congratulations, in my opinion it is a great and very interesting question.

Comment: @jccampanero thanks for your informative answer. is there any priority between these three? In what order are they used?

Comment: You are very. welcome @hatefalipoor. No actually: it will be depend on your actual use case. What are you trying to achieve? What is your actual use case?

Comment: @jccampanero thanks. I'm just learning Spring and get confused when encountered these terms and your answer clarified a lot. sorry I'm asking a lot. when we use `@RequestBody` Spring uses `HttpMessageConverter` to do the conversion and when we use `@ModelAttribute` for example in form submission Spring uses one of `PropertyEditor` or `Formatter` or `Converter`? is my understanding correct?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @hatefalipoor. Please, you can ask everything you consider appropriate. In fact, it is a very good and, in a certain way, "tricky" question. I would say yes, it can be summarized like that, they are typical use cases. But please, be aware that, as I tried to explain in the answer, `PropertyEditor`s, `Formatter`s and `Converter`s are general constructs, and they can be used anywhere in the framework, although as I said, I think you summarized it very well.